# Confusing Peltier Power Draw

Tags: current, amperage, peltier

**Essential Question: Which Peltier is the most Efficient for reaching coolest temperature, and is the 6V 2A peltier inefficient?**

I was looking into more efficient Peltiers for my project and tried to test the amperages of certain Peltiers on a 5V power supply.

Here are the results I have up with:

Using a 5V power supply,

- TEC-12704 (12V 4A standard draw) drew 5V 1.4A.
- Peltier TEC-12705 (12V 5A standard draw) drew 5V 1.36A.

I don't understand how a Peltier rated higher than the previously mentioned runs at a lower power, and furthermore, when converting 12V -> 5V current output using ratios, (12V/5A = 5V/XA, where a 12V 5A Peltier should draw 5V 2.083 Amps? Why is this happening!

- Lastly, I tested a 6V 2A Peltier which ran at 5V 2.2 Amps, more amperage at a lower voltage? - **so does that mean this is inefficient compared to the last 2 Peltiers?**

Currently I am using the 6V 2A Peltier, trying to find a more efficient Peltier and need to figure out: are these weird numbers due to one Peltier being more efficient than the other (critical to my project) or something else?

Comment: There is a back emf due to seebeck of junctions between Peltier plates, resulting in less current for same Vin

Comment: @sstobbe hi, could you explain this a little bit more: I am a super beginner. Also, if you could explain this in terms of efficiency that would be great

Comment: Hi, if you disconnect your 5V supply after some time and measure the terminals of the peltier you  will find its generating a voltage proportional to the temperature differential across it

Comment: @sstobbe interesting: well, based on these reading, is the 6V2A peltier inefficient, because I need to tell the efficiencies of the peltiers to see what I should buy out of the 3, or should I go for a higher powered one?

Comment: https://www.meerstetter.ch/compendium/tec-peltier-element-design-guide#choosingtec

Comment: Efficiency of a peltier has very little to do with V & I...

Comment: @Trevor_G what determines the efficiency of a Peltier?

Comment: Thermal transfer characteristics. Watts of heat pumped/Watts of electricity put in.

Comment: @Trevor_G and how can I determine the efficiencies of my Peltiers, is there anything you can see about them that may say which one is more efficient? The 6V 2A Peltier gets much closer than the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to do an in depth analysis for you. Even if I did, how you mechanically arrange the device to transfer the heat effects the efficiency of the system far more than anything else.